# Two Tables Excel values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables in two different sheets. In Table 1 and table 2 column 1 is for id's. but in Table 2 I have more id's than table 1.

What I want is: if a cell in table 2 column 2 is filled to check the id and if its in table 2 to mark "yes" in column 2 in Table 1.

This is the code I have been using but it stops when the ids don't match:

`=IF(AND(Table 2[column 2]>0,VLOOKUP([column 1],Table 2[column 1],1,FALSE)=sheet 2!A5),"yes","")`

Answer (score 0):

You could put something like this in table 1 column 2.  Assuming table 1 is in columns A,B and Table 2 is in columns D,E.  That is column D is the id in table 2 and column E is the value in table 2.

This will return an error if there is an id in table 1 that isn't in table 2.  To deal with this you could wrap it with **iferror**.

```
=IF(INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(A1,$D:$D,0))>0,"yes","")
```

Gordon

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(Table1[[#This Row],[column 1]],Table2[#All],2,0)<>"","yes",""),"")
```

at the top of column 2 of Table1, adding spaces in the table names if you have been able to.